# Limit function to specific post category

Tags: posts, categories, functions, images, css

I have a function that wraps images in a custom div.

It's placed in functions.php and modifies all posts. I'd like to know if there's a way to *only* apply it to posts in a certain category.

Here's the function:

```
function my_image_tag($html, $id , $alt, $title) {
    $html = "<div class='my-class'>" . $html . "</div>";
    return $html;
}

add_filter('get_image_tag','my_image_tag',10,4);
```

### Update:

Robert Hue's method didn't work with this function, but it worked with the following function, which I think is better (at least for my use):

```
function wrapImagesInDiv($content) {
    if ( in_category( 'prosjekter' ) ) {
        $pattern = '/(<img[^>]*class=\"([^>]*?)\"[^>]*>)/i';
        $replacement = '<div class="image-container $2">$1</div>';
        $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
    }
    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'wrapImagesInDiv');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check for category posts to modify content. Specify category ID (integer), name or slug (string), or an array of these in in_category check.

```
function my_image_tag( $html, $id , $alt, $title ) {
    if ( in_category( '1' ) ) {
        $html = "<div class='my-class'>" . $html . "</div>";
    }
    return $html;
}

add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'my_image_tag', 10 ,4 );
```

For category slug `blog-post` you can use `in_category( 'blog-post' )`

If you want to use more then 1 category then you can do something like.

```
in_category( array( '15', 'Tropical Birds', 'small-mammals' ) )
```

It's a combination of ID, Name and slug. SO it's up to you how you can to use it.

**EDIT**

If you are using this outside loop then try this.

```
function my_image_tag( $html, $id , $alt, $title ) {
    global $post;
    if ( in_category( '1' ) ) {
        $html = "<div class='my-class'>" . $html . "</div>";
    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'get_image_tag', 'my_image_tag', 10 ,4 );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I tried both ID and slug. Does the placement of this function have anything to say?

Comment: If your code is working then it should work too... I only added category condition in this function.

Comment: Hm. Quite sure it's not working. I have it in functions.php, perhaps I should try placing it in the loop? Will report back if I have any progress.

Comment: This tag can be used to test the current post within The Loop or outside the Loop during a single post request. You can use it anywhere if you specify which post you want to test.

Comment: Check edit in answer.

Comment: I gave up with that one and found a better function that modifies the generated content with preg_replace instead. This one works with your method. Thanks!

Comment: Cool ;) that sounds great. What exactly are you trying to do? Are you adding all images into div.

Comment: I'm using [OWL Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) to display all the images in a slider, and I need them to be placed within a certain DIV. It's quite possible it would've been easier to modify the OWL Carousel's scripts or settings, but I tried this method first :P